# Finding the Integer part of $\sum_{k=2} ^{9999}\frac{1}{\sqrt k}$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, limits

Question from Model Question Paper for B.Math/B.Stat: [Page 28, Question 27](http://www.isical.ac.in/~deanweb/sample/BST-BMT2013.pdf) by [Indian Statistical Institute](http://www.isical.ac.in/)

Q. Assume the following inequalities for positive k:

$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{k+1}}< \sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt k<\frac{1}{2\sqrt k}$$

The Integer part of: 
$$\sum_{k=2} ^{9999}\frac{1}{\sqrt k}$$ equals:

A. $198$

B. $197$

C. $196$

D. $195$

My approach:

$$S=\sum_{k=2} ^{9999}\frac{1}{\sqrt k}$$
$$S=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}+ \cdots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{9999}}$$
$$S=2\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt 2}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt 3}+ \cdots + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{9999}}\right)$$
$$S\approx 2\left((\sqrt 2- \sqrt 1) + (\sqrt3- \sqrt2)+\cdots +(\sqrt{9999}-\sqrt{9998})\right)$$
$$[S]\approx2(\sqrt{9999}-\sqrt1)$$
$$[S]\approx 2(98)$$
$$[S]=196$$

I know my method is not an efficient one.
Also I don't know if the answer is correct. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The answer is B: 197. For an effective way to see how to do it, without much calculations at all- see my answer. You only need to find $\sqrt{10,000}$ and $\sqrt{1}$

Answer (score 6):

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{9999}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}<2(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{9999}{\sqrt{k+1}}-\sqrt k)< \sum\limits_{k=1}^{9999}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$.

Now, the sum $2(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{9999}{\sqrt{k+1}}-\sqrt k)$ telescopes, to give us 198.

We thus have:

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{9999}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}< 198$. So, $\sum\limits_{k=2}^{10,000}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k}} < 198$, and

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{9999}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k}} > 198$.

Now do the obvious little manipulations, to get your answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If we analyze what you have done, the procedure you used yields the fact that $S\lt 2(\sqrt{9999}-\sqrt{1})\approx 197.99$.

You need to use the other inequality to show in the same way that $S\gt 2(\sqrt{10000}-\sqrt{2})$.

The two results combined will give you the answer.